# Как создать в Visual Composer свой Shortcode с изображением?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, visual-composer

Мне нужно создать элемент, где будет 3 поля описания и одно изображение.

Как создавать шорткоды с текстовыми полями я разобрался, но у меня не получается добавить изображение, а точнее, вывести его на сайте. В админской части оно появляется, но на сайте вместо изображения выводятся цифры.

Суть вопроса: как добавить изображение в шорткод?)

Вот мой новый шорткод в коде. Сейчас он без изображения.

Подключал в functions.php таким кодом

```
/ Before VC Init
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_before_init_actions' );

function vc_before_init_actions() {

//.. Code from other Tutorials ..//

// Require new custom Element
require_once( get_template_directory().'/vc-elements/my-first-custom-element.php' ); }
```

Это код самого шорткода (без изображения)

```
<?php
/*
Element Description: VC Info Box
*/

// Element Class 
class vcInfoBox extends WPBakeryShortCode {

// Element Init
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'vc_infobox_mapping' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'vc_infobox', array( $this, 'vc_infobox_html' ) );
}

// Element Mapping
public function vc_infobox_mapping() {

    // Stop all if VC is not enabled
if ( !defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) {
        return;
}

// Map the block with vc_map()
vc_map( 

    array(
        'name' => __('VC Infobox', 'text-domain'),
        'base' => 'vc_infobox',
        'description' => __('Another simple VC box', 'text-domain'), 
        'category' => __('Stimul', 'text-domain'),   
        'icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/image/Logo.png',            
        'params' => array(   

            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'h3',
                'class' => 'title-class',
                'heading' => __( 'Title', 'text-domain' ),
                'param_name' => 'title',
                'value' => __( 'Default value', 'text-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Box Title', 'text-domain' ),
                'admin_label' => false,
                'weight' => 0,
                'group' => 'Custom Group',
            ),  

            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => 'text-class',
                'heading' => __( 'Price', 'text-domain' ),
                'param_name' => 'price',
                'value' => __( 'Default value', 'text-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Box Text', 'text-domain' ),
                'admin_label' => false,
                'weight' => 0,
                'group' => 'Custom Group',
            ), 
      array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => 'text-class',
                'heading' => __( 'Text desc', 'text-domain' ),
                'param_name' => 'text',
                'value' => __( 'Default value', 'text-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Box Text', 'text-domain' ),
                'admin_label' => false,
                'weight' => 0,
                'group' => 'Custom Group',
            ),

    array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => 'card-button-card',
                'heading' => __( 'text-Button', 'text-button' ),
                'param_name' => 'button',
                'value' => __( 'Default value', 'button-text-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Box button', 'text-button' ),
                'admin_label' => false,
                'weight' => 0,
                'group' => 'Custom Group',
            ) ,

    array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => 'card-button-URL',
                'heading' => __( 'URL', 'text-button-URL' ),
                'param_name' => 'url',
                'value' => __( 'Default value', 'button-text-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Box button url', 'text-url' ),
                'admin_label' => false,
                'weight' => 0,
                'group' => 'Custom Group',
            )

        )
    )
);                                


} 


// Element HTML
public function vc_infobox_html( $atts ) {

    // Params extraction
extract(
    shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'title'   => '',
            'text' => '',

    'button' => '',
    'price' => '',
    'url' => '',
        ), 
        $atts
    )
);

// Fill $html var with data
$html = '
<div class="vc-infobox-wrap">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="vc-infobox-title">' . $title . '</div></div>

   <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="vc-infobox-price">' . $price . '</div>
 <div class="vc-infobox-text">' . $text . '</div></div>

<div class="col-md-6"><div class="vc-infobox-button"><a class="card-button-card" href="' . $url . '">' . $button . '</a></div></div>
 </div>
</div>';      

return $html;

} 

} // End Element Class

// Element Class Init
new vcInfoBox();
```

Comment: А изображение-то как выводите?

Comment: <div class="vc-infobox-image">' . $image . '</div>
Но я понимаю что это не правильно.
Как правильно, найти не смог(
Вот и спрашиваю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цифры, которые выводятся - это id изображения, насколько я понимаю. Из вопроса этого понять нельзя, но Visual Composer оперирует с ними.

Как из id получить изображение?

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image, 'full' );
echo '<div class="vc-infobox-image"><img src="' . $image_url . '"></div>';
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую, и опишусь)

Comment: KAGG Design ОГРОМНОЕ ЧЕЛОВЕЧЕСКОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!
Все получилось!)
Я два дня мучился)